# Could not find function or function reference 'pow'

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Getting this error on Pinescript 5
Could not find function or function reference 'pow'

Code line:
sc = pow(er * (fastsc - slowsc) + slowsc, 2)

Getting this error on Pinescript 5
Could not find function or function reference 'pow'

Code line:
sc = pow(er * (fastsc - slowsc) + slowsc, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use math.pow(base, exponent) in PineScript V5
see [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_math{dot}pow](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_math%7Bdot%7Dpow)